# python how to slice a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

what I have:

```
[{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 1, 'fields': {'name': 'Solar modules', 'name_el': 'Φωτοβολταικά πλαίσια', 'name_de': 'Solarmodul'}}, {'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'DC cables', 'name_el': 'DC καλώδια', 'name_de': 'DC-Kabel'}}, {'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 3, 'fields': {'name': 'DC combiner boxes', 'name_el': 'DC πίνακες', 'name_de': 'DC-Anschlussgehäuse'}}]

for i in range (0,20):
    print(d[i])
```

The output

```
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 1, 'fields': {'name': 'Solar modules', 'name_el': 'Φωτοβολταικά πλαίσια', 'name_de': 'Solarmodul'}}
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'DC cables', 'name_el': 'DC καλώδια', 'name_de': 'DC-Kabel'}}
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 3, 'fields': {'name': 'DC combiner boxes', 'name_el': 'DC πίνακες', 'name_de': 'DC-Anschlussgehäuse'}}
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 4, 'fields': {'name': 'Inverters', 'name_el': 'Μετατροπείς', 'name_de': 'Wechselrichter'}}
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 5, 'fields': {'name': 'AC cables', 'name_el': 'ΑC καλώδια', 'name_de': 'AC-Kabel'}}
{'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 6, 'fields': {'name': 'AC combiner boxes', 'name_el': 'AC πίνακες', 'name_de': 'AC-Anschlussgehäuse'}}
```

what I need is a json file that includes only the `'name'` and `'name_el'` like the following:

```
{
"Solar modules": "Φωτοβολταικά πλαίσια",
"DC cables": "DC καλώδια",
}
```

Thank you for any help. At the same time I am trying to solve it as well.

Comment: So you have a *list* of dictionaries? You need to add an example of *exactly* what you have.

Comment: It's really not clear what you are after. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to improve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i get your question right, this is what you want:

```
lst = [
    {'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 1, 'fields': {'name':'Solar modules', 'name_el': 'Φωτοβολταικά πλαίσια', 'name_de': 'Solarmodul'}},
    {'model': 're_catalogue.component', 'pk': 2, 'fields': {'name': 'DC cables', 'name_el': 'DC καλώδια', 'name_de': 'DC-Kabel'}}
]

result = dict()
for i in lst:
    result[i['fields']['name']] = i['fields']['name_el']
print(result)
# {
#    "Solar modules": "Φωτοβολταικά πλαίσια",
#    "DC cables": "DC καλώδια"
# }
```

Answer (score 3):

By using a dict comprehension you'll get a dict with the desired output
(assuming your list of dicts is called `lst` ):

```
{i['fields']['name']:i['fields']['name_el'] for i in lst}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new_dict = {}
for e in d:
    new_dict[e['fields']['name']] = e['fields']['name_el']
```